# Error installing docker on other partition

Tags: docker

I installed Kubuntu 18 about 3 weeks ago on partition in 28G(sdb5), but after installing of docker seems this space is not enough for my root partition 
I found that /var/lib/docker/ takes 11.1 GiB.

I found a decision of using sdb7 partition for docker which is not used now. 
So after I formatted /sdb7 into ext4 and used /sdb7 in /etc/fstab and restarted OS I run:

```
cd /var/lib
sudo rsync -av docker /mnt/_work_sdb7
sudo mv docker docker.old
sudo ln -s /mnt/_work_sdb7/docker
```

and next :

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localunixsocket - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

I found a way of fixing such error:

```
sudo  usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo  newgrp - docker
```

But it did not help. Next :

Some configation/permittions missing?

```
# docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.17.1, build unknown
# docker --version
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

**MODIFIED :**

I run command and see messages in console :

```
$ sudo dockerd --data-root=/mnt/_work_sdb7
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.394402307+03:00] Starting up                                  
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.395196810+03:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.444127000+03:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.444152461+03:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.444179994+03:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.444193376+03:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.444651765+03:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000143020, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.444710232+03:00] blockingPicker: the picked transport is not ready, loop back to repick  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.463935589+03:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000143020, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503211493+03:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503236499+03:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503253831+03:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] }  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503264403+03:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503334016+03:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000143420, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503354596+03:00] blockingPicker: the picked transport is not ready, loop back to repick  module=grpc
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.503629147+03:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000143420, READY  module=grpc
WARN[2019-09-14T14:56:26.584401464+03:00] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit 
WARN[2019-09-14T14:56:26.584423249+03:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[2019-09-14T14:56:26.584431948+03:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.584832727+03:00] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:26.861388365+03:00] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:27.120567034+03:00] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:27.294102345+03:00] Docker daemon                                 commit=6a30dfc graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.2
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:27.294224407+03:00] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[2019-09-14T14:56:27.366695106+03:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

The command above did not finish and was working:

I opened console in other tab and run :

```
$ sudo  usermod -aG docker $USER
$ sudo  newgrp - docker
# cd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker
# sudo systemctl enable docker
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
# sudo systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-14 15:00:34 EEST; 8s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 14694 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14694 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
# journalctl -xe
-- Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Sep 14 15:00:34 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Sep 14 15:00:42 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
-- Subject: Unit anacron.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit anacron.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Sep 14 15:00:42 serge-at-hoe anacron[14760]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2019-09-14
Sep 14 15:00:42 serge-at-hoe anacron[14760]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
```

What is wrong ?

**MODIFIED 2 :**
I did not find existing file, so I created new file /etc/docker/daemon.json
with content :

```
{
  "data-root": "/mnt/_work_sdb7/docker" ,
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}


/etc/docker# ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 вер 14 16:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 150 root root 12288 вер 14 16:05 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root    81 вер 14 16:52 daemon.json
-rw-------   1 root root   244 вер  6 18:12 key.json
```

In my /etc/fstab :

```
/dev/sdb7 /mnt/_work_sdb7  ext4 defaults 0 0
```

and restarted the OS.
After that in my docker project I run :

```
$ sudo systemctl enable docker
[sudo] password for serge: 
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
serge@serge-at-hoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ sudo systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
serge@serge-at-hoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-09-14 16:54:09 EEST; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5199 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5199 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
serge@serge-at-hoe:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ journalctl -xe
-- 
-- Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Closed Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.socket has finished shutting down.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Stopping Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support                                                                                                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- Unit docker.socket has begun shutting down.                                                                                                                                                                                               
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.                                                                                                                                                                 
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has begun start-up                                                                                                                                                                                            
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support                                                                                                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- Unit docker.socket has begun starting up.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.                                                                                                                                                             
-- Subject: Unit docker.socket has finished start-up                                                                                                                                                                                         
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support                                                                                                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- Unit docker.socket has finished starting up.                                                                                                                                                                                              
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
вер 14 16:54:10 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=100.103.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=40300 PROTO=2 
вер 14 16:54:10 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=213.109.129.134 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=250 ID=15541 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35673 DPT=23 WINDOW=14600 R
вер 14 16:54:11 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=36.63.165.72 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=115 ID=901 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=44000 DPT=1433 WINDOW=8192 RES=0
вер 14 16:54:12 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=100.103.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=48963 PROTO=2 
вер 14 16:54:23 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=159.224.38.32 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=26239 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34959 DPT=6881 WINDOW=7300 RES
вер 14 16:54:23 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=185.222.211.54 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=251 ID=1768 PROTO=TCP SPT=41109 DPT=8321 WINDOW=1024 RES=0
вер 14 16:54:23 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=87.122.153.155 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=2867 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47437 DPT=6881 WINDOW=7300 RES
вер 14 16:54:24 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=159.224.38.32 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=26240 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34959 DPT=6881 WINDOW=7300 RES
вер 14 16:54:24 serge-at-hoe kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0 OUT= MAC=44:8a:5b:ee:2a:dd:c8:e7:f0:6e:fc:29:08:00 SRC=87.122.153.155 DST=213.109.234.130 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=2868 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47437 DPT=6881 WINDOW=7300 RES
lines 2823-2877/2877 (END)
```

I see errors :

```
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
вер 14 16:54:09 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

?

**MODIFIED 3 :**
I found /etc/systemd/system.conf in which all parameters were commented
I uncommented or added parameters with some values, incrementing them and restarting OS. I made so several times and at least I have :

```
DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec=350s
DefaultStartLimitBurst=260
StartLimitInterval=350s
StartLimitBurst=260
StartLimitIntervalSec=260
```

while all the rest parameters commented, But any way I see errors :

```
вер 14 18:05:44 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
вер 14 18:05:44 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
вер 14 18:05:44 serge-at-hoe systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Which values must have these(or some others) values ?

**MODIFIED # 4 :**
I tried in /etc/systemd/system.conf to change some values to zero, as I googled such possible decision:

```
DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec=0
DefaultStartLimitBurst=260
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=260
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
```

But restarting OS I failed to login into the system and has a lot of flash messages on the screen.
I modified the file with all 0 :

```
DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec=0
DefaultStartLimitBurst=0
StartLimitInterval=0
StartLimitBurst=0
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
```

I reloaded ok but running docker I still have "Start request repeated too quickly" errors:

```
$ sudo  usermod -aG docker $USER
#:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker$ sudo  newgrp - docker
#:/root# cd /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker
#:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker# sudo systemctl start docker   
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
#:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker# sudo systemctl enable docker
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable docker
#:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker# sudo systemctl start docker   
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
#:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2019-09-16 14:30:07 EEST; 298ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 5183 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5183 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 16 14:30:07 s systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 16 14:30:07 s systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 16 14:30:07 s systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 16 14:30:07 s systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 16 14:30:07 s systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 14:30:07 s systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
#:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/DockerApps/votes_docker# journalctl -xe
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
-- Subject: Unit snapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit snapd.service has begun starting up.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s snapd[6435]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Sep 16 14:30:15 s snapd[6435]: cannot run daemon: assert storage root unexpectedly world-writable: /var/lib/snapd/assertions/asserts-v0
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.                                                                                                                                                      
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.                                                                                                                                                                      
-- Subject: Unit snapd.service has failed                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support                                                                                                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- Unit snapd.service has failed.                                                                                                                                                                                                            
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- The result is RESULT.                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.                                                                                                                                                  
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.                                                                                                                                      
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 25663.                                                                                                                                  
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled                                                                                                                                                                                
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support                                                                                                                                                                                                    
--                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-- Automatic restarting of the unit snapd.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: Stopped Snappy daemon.
-- Subject: Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit snapd.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: Starting Snappy daemon...
-- Subject: Unit snapd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit snapd.service has begun starting up.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s snapd[6467]: AppArmor status: apparmor is enabled and all features are available
Sep 16 14:30:15 s snapd[6467]: cannot run daemon: assert storage root unexpectedly world-writable: /var/lib/snapd/assertions/asserts-v0
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: Failed to start Snappy daemon.
-- Subject: Unit snapd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit snapd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
Sep 16 14:30:15 s systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

I am not sure if that valid options in  /etc/systemd/system.conf or some other issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you typed:

```
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The way you are trying to install docker on another partition is not correct.

- You need a partition (`sdb7` in your case). Suppose its mounted at `/mnt/sdb7`
- Docker by default store all its data (containers, images and so on) in `/var/lib/docker` you need to change this in your case to something like `/mnt/sdb7/docker` using [data-root](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#run-multiple-daemons) option of docker.

While starting docker deamon use `--data-root` option.

```
dockerd --data-root=/mnt/sdb7/docker
```

Hope this helps.

**Update:**

The `dockerd` command will run in foreground.

You need to set `--data-root` option permanently for `docker.service` that you start/stop using `systemctl`.

To set that option permanently refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options).

You need to add this line `"data-root": "/mnt/docker-data"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file.

**Update-2:**

`docker.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'` means docker.service seems to fail and restart to fast. The is explained [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/845471/service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-refusing-to-start-limit).

You need to edit systemd file for docker using `systemctl edit docker.service` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33931#issuecomment-453840775) and tweak the values of `StartLimitIntervalSec=` and `StartLimitBurst=` as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/845471/service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-refusing-to-start-limit) so that the `docker.service` will not fail to quickly.

**Update-3:**

Editing `/etc/systemd/system.conf` file is dangerous it might cause serious problem with your VM. What I suggested was to change make change using `systemctl edit docker.service`.

The docker.service systemd file contents should be similar to [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/init/systemd/docker.service).
Also refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#manually-create-the-systemd-unit-files).

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED :

Comment: Updated my answer please check.

Comment: Please,look at MODIFIED 2 :

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED 3

Comment: I still search for a decision. Please look MODIFIED # 4